# 10 MHz frequency standard input

Tags: frequency, gps, standard

Many sampled data systems accept a 10 MHz frequency standard. I'm designing a sampled data system, and would like to include the ability to lock to an external clock reference.

I've seen many different outputs, I have one GPS reference that puts out 13 dBm into a 50 ohm load, a distribution amplifier that puts out 1 V p-p into a 50 ohm load, and I'm sure there's many others, so I'm a bit confused as to what inputs I should be able to cope with to make this system versatile.

Is there a standard or a suggested range for a 10 MHz frequency reference input?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

1V (=13dBm at 50Ohm) is fairly standard.

Source: have lots of expensive spectrum analyzers on my desk.

Comment: Thanks much, after hunting around a bit more, you're quite right.